# How to Replace Text Output from For Loop with Different Values in p5.js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, processing, p5.js

New to coding and working in p5.js here...the struggle is real. I've created a digital clock, and used an array and for loops to output the time values of the clock around it's periphery (1-12). I've also made the clock  tick. I've also set it so that when the ticker passes a certain value, text next to the ticker changes from "human!" to "wear wolf!" (weird project, I know.). Each time the ticker passes the pre-set value, I've also set the code to change the time values on the clock from 1-12 to say "HOWL" instead. However, I can still see the 1-12 time value numbers behind the word "HOWL" and can't figure out how to remove them.

How do I do this? Thanks for any advice! Code is below:

```
//var line = line(0,0,x,y);
var radius = 110.0;
var angle = 0.0;
var x=0, y=0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
}

function draw() {

  background(255);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  stroke(205,205,55);
  fill(255,0,255);
  ellipse(0,0,10,10);
  noFill();
  ellipse(0,0,250,250);
  stroke(25);


  var angleOffset = -1*PI/2; //create variable//
  for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) { //generate 12 numbers//
   angle = 2*PI*i/12 + angleOffset; //what is this? another variable? //
   text(i, radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle));
  }
  //text outputs the i generated in for loop, then x and y coordinates times the angle set//
  if (x < TWO_PI/2) { 

  //fill(10,10,124);
  fill(10,105,55);
  text("WEARWOLF", x+10, y+15);

  var angleOffset = -1*PI/2; //create variable//
  for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) { //generate 12 numbers//
   angle = 2*PI*i/12 + angleOffset; //what is this? another variable? //
   text("HOWL", radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))
   noFill();
   text(i, radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))

  }
   } else {
  noFill();
  text("HUMAN!", x+10, y+5);
  //ellipse(0,0,250,250)


 }



  angle = (second() / 59.0) * TWO_PI;

  // memorize this formula, it's helpful
  x = cos(angle)* radius;
  y = sin(angle)* radius;

  stroke(255,0,255);

  //draw a line from the center of our screen and as long as our radius

  line(0,0,x,y);
  ellipse(x,y,10,10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper indenting to make it more obvious what your code is doing:

```js
var radius = 110.0;
var angle = 0.0;
var x=0, y=0;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
}

function draw() {

    background(255);
    translate(width/2, height/2);
    stroke(205,205,55);
    fill(255,0,255);
    ellipse(0,0,10,10);
    noFill();
    ellipse(0,0,250,250);
    stroke(25);


    var angleOffset = -1*PI/2; //create variable//

    for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) { //generate 12 numbers//
        angle = 2*PI*i/12 + angleOffset; //what is this? another variable? //
        text(i, radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle));
    }

    //text outputs the i generated in for loop, then x and y coordinates times the angle set//
    if (x < TWO_PI/2) { 
        fill(10,105,55);
        text("WEARWOLF", x+10, y+15);

        var angleOffset = -1*PI/2; //create variable//
        for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) { //generate 12 numbers//
            angle = 2*PI*i/12 + angleOffset; //what is this? another variable? //
            text("HOWL", radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))
            noFill();
            text(i, radius*cos(angle), radius*sin(angle))

        }
    } else {
        noFill();
        text("HUMAN!", x+10, y+5);
        //ellipse(0,0,250,250)
    }

    angle = (second() / 59.0) * TWO_PI;

    // memorize this formula, it's helpful
    x = cos(angle)* radius;
    y = sin(angle)* radius;

    stroke(255,0,255);

    //draw a line from the center of our screen and as long as our radius
    line(0,0,x,y);
    ellipse(x,y,10,10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.4.23/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now check out the code in your `draw()` function. Notice the first `for` loop: you're **always** drawing the numbers 1-12!

Then you have an `if` statement that checks whether `x < TWO_PI/2` (note: why not just use pi?). When that if statement evaluates to true, then you draw `"HOWL"` around the clock. But wait, you already drew the `1-12`!

You're going to have to modify your code so that you only draw the `1-12` **or** `"HOWL"`.

There are two ways to do that:

**Option 1:** Move the first for loop into the `else{}` section of your code. That way you only draw the `1-12` when you draw the `"HUMAN!" label.

**Option 2:** Only use a single for loop, but move your if statement inside that for loop. Here's a skeleton:

```
for (var i=1; i<=12; i++) {
   if (x < TWO_PI/2) { 
      //draw HOWL
   }
   else{
      //draw the number
   }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer (+1). Converting from cartesian to polar coordinates may be harder for beginners, perhaps a ```push()/pop()``` option would achieve the same using rotation and translation.

Comment: Thank to you both! It worked. I used TWO_PI randomly...I was just experimenting on where to set that if, else because I am super rusty on trigonometry. Any ideas on what I could do to set it to switch more often?